# Adding residual connections to simple CNN

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I implemented the following CNN with *residual connections* for classification of 10 classes on CIFAR10:

```
class ConvolutionalNetwork(nn.Module):  

  def __init__(self, filters=[32, 32, 32]):

    super(ConvolutionalNetwork, self).__init__()

    self.conv = []
    self.filters = filters
    in_channels = 3

    for out_channels in self.filters:
      self.conv.append(nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, 5, padding=2))
      in_channels = out_channels

    self.conv = nn.ModuleList(self.conv)
    self.fc = nn.Linear(self.filters[-1] * 32 * 32, 10)

  def forward(self, X):
    X = X.contiguous()

    for i, conv in enumerate(self.conv):
      res = X
      X = F.relu(conv(X))
      X += res

    X = X.reshape(-1,self.filters[-1]*self.size*self.size)

    X = self.fc(X)
    return F.log_softmax(X, dim=1)
```

Basically: Conv2d(5x5) --> ReLU --> Conv2d(5x5) --> ReLU --> Conv2d(5x5) --> ReLU --> Fully Connected Layer --> SoftMax
The performence with the *residual connections* is worse then without. I wonder:

1. maybe I didn't use it right (should I use nn.Identity() or some other pytorch class?)
2. what are the best practices for number of filters (I tried [32,32,32] and [64,64,64]) and for skips (how many hops? i did one but maybe this is the problem?)
3. How can I change the dimention of the identity to fit varying dimentions of the convolutional network (i.e. [16, 32, 64] filters)

Answer (score 1):

I think only three layers is not deep enough for the residual links to "kick in" - I guess this is the main reason why training without residual connections works better.
Moreover, your fully-connected layer has 32K input dimension - this is HUGE.

How does your residual link works for the first conv layer where `res` has 3 channels and `X` has 32?

I would try the following:

1. Do not add residual links for the first conv layer.
2. Add `nn.BatchNorm2d` after the conv and before the `relu`.
3. Add strides - sub sample the feature maps, so you'll end up with significantly less than 32K features for the fully connected layer.